# Get 4 distinct forms (initial, medial, final or isolated) of Arabic Unicode characters of the given string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode, arabic

I have Arabic content like ضضضضضضض. I want to get the Unicode code points of all forms of the letters (initial, medial, final or isolated) in the given string.

Comment: You want the code of every character?

Comment: yes @yogur. I need to know all characters unicodes

Comment: The four distinct forms of a letter all have one code, regardless of a letter's position in a word. The shape of a letter is handled by fonts, not by unicode.

Comment: nope @yo in my example ضضضضضضض are stored as a standard Dhad ض \u0636 but shown as:

ﺿ  \ufebf (start)
ﻀ  \ufec0 (middle)
ﺾ  \ufebe (end)
ﺽ  \ufebd (independent)

Comment: I'm not aware of anything except re-implementing the logic used to render the glyphs in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Javascript library (not mine) can do this for you: https://github.com/louy/Javascript-Arabic-Reshaper

This will take a string that uses only the 'generic' characters and return you a new string with all the correct position-specific replacements done for you. From there, you can just grab the character code (or code point) at each position.

Here is a sample usage:

```
//import the library
var ArabicReshaper = require('arabic-reshaper');

// This can be a plain string. I just want to make sure I am feeding
// it the "plain" letter, not the initial/middle/end forms
var originalString = String.fromCharCode(0x0636, 0x0636); //ضض

// this will convert it to the 'shaped' letters. that means the letters
// will be transformed into the 'initial/middle/end' forms in the string
// (not just when it draws to the screen.
var newString = ArabicReshaper.convertArabic(originalString);

// And get the values. These will be the specific initial/middle/end values, not the generic ones
console.log(
    newString.codePointAt(0).toString(16), // outputs febf
    newString.codePointAt(1).toString(16) // outputs febe
);
```