# need shaped forms for arabic letters

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, fonts, arabic

In Arabic, a character shows up differently depending on whether it is at the beginning of a word, middle, or end.

e.g. يَسْتَفْعِلُ
The second last consonant, ع -- looks like this when written independently.
But looks very different when inside the word, ﻌ - as you can see.

I want to show the shaped form in a div.
When I copy just one letter from above word, it pastes like ع
I want ﻌ

I tried splitting the word into letters in Ruby, no luck.
I tried splitting in JS, no luck.

My final goal is to render this in HTML. Given an Arabic word, find its broken parts, retaining their shaped forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get 4 distinct forms (initial, medial, final or isolated) of Arabic Unicode characters of the given string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366366/get-4-distinct-forms-initial-medial-final-or-isolated-of-arabic-unicode-char)

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as needing to be more "focused" as this is a clear and reasonable question related to Unicode. The Unicode character U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER is an invisible format control that behaves like a left- and right-joining character when placed before or after an Arabic character. To make AIN appear in isolation as though it were in a word-medial position, use the character sequence <U+200D, U+0639, U+200D. Within HTML, use &#x200d; before and after ع: &#x200d;ع&#x200d;

Comment: @gog that's fantastic, if you give that as an answer I'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: @KazimZaidi To be clear, are you happy that [the answer to the question that gog linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367438/2985643) solves your problem? If so, we should close your question as a duplicate of that one.